# autoresizingmask function not showing in Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, autoresizingmask

I want to deal with autoresizingmasks, but for some reason I can't get the dialogue to show up.  The size inspector of my IB looks like this:

[image]

When I click on another inspector--attributes, connections, etc.--the autoresizingmasks dialogue/inspector appears for an instant (not long enough for me to grab a screen shot), only to be replaced by whatever inspector I've clicked on.  I assume I've got some setting or other toggled that I need to untoggle, but poking around Xcode hasn't revealed it, and I haven't found this problem in other questions on Xcode.  Obviously a very basic question, but can anybody help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

File Inspector -> Interface Builder Document -> Use Autolayout[UNCHECK]

Autolayout is a new OSX7/iOS6 feature using Constraints (as you can see from that inspector)
- it replaces Autoresizing masks, but only works on OSX7+ and iOS6+